# "isSearchable" field limit constraint is per localized value or per attribute definition?

Tags: commercetools

Current documentation states: "The max size of a searchable field is restricted to 10922 characters. This constraint is enforced at both product creation and product update. If the length of the input exceeds the maximum size an InvalidField error is returned"

If i have localized field/attribute of type "ltext" will constraint be applied for each localized value or on total length of all localized values of an attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localized text is modeled as an object with field for every language tag. This means that the constraint would be applied individually on every localized value.